# Change attribute position in woocommerce - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I have three product attribute Size, Color and gender and I want to change the position of those attribute from this [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59r6E.png) to this [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VANQ.png) in woocommerce single product page. Please help me how can i do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with expected output and actual output.